# Abort node+express request if same client sends another on the same route before the first can finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

My client triggers a new search request for every change to an input field. Search results return as they type.

But this produces too many needless requests for the server to process.

I already abort requests on the client end using jquery's ajax abort function. But this doesn't prevent the server from continuing to process the request.

I want to abort requests which have started on the server when a new request comes in from the same client on the same route.

How would I go about doing this, preferably using plain old express and node.

Here is a simplified version of my existing route

```js
router.post('/search', async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const result = db.search(req);
    res.json(result);
  } catch (e) {
    res.send(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: You should use `debounce` to limit the rate of request from client for such use cases.

Comment: I am already using a timeout function on the client to slow down requests. And there is no search button. Requests fire automatically 500ms after someone types.

Comment: As said above try a `debounce` function, such as [this one](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function). Quoted from the link: "Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for N milliseconds.". So basically the requests will not be send while the user is typing, but rather X ms after the typing has stopped.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, I'm already debouncing. Requests are sent only if someone stops typing for 500ms. Client-side, I am all set. I want to cancel an ongoing request via node, per my question.